# How to protect Login and Register components if user loggedin?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have login register and some other routes releated with their components.I can protect other routes under the loginComponent but I don't want user to see login component by changing url by hand if user loggedIn and register.

user is able to go to login component by texting "/" on URL and I want to prevent this if user LoggedIn

**Here my route config below**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
    {
        path:'',
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        children:[
            {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
            {path: 'appointments', component: AppointmentsComponent},
            {path: 'appointmentPicker', component: AppointmentPickerComponent},
        ]
    },
    {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent},
    {path:'**',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
  ];
```

**AuthGuard**

```
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router:Router){

    }
    canActivate(): boolean{
       if(this.authService.loggedIn()){
         return true;
       }
       else{
         this.router.navigate(['']);
       }
    }
  }
```

**SOLUTION(UPDATED)**
Here what I tried and worked exactly I wanted.Thank you all

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  model:any={};
  tokenExist:boolean=false;
  logInWorked:boolean=false;
  constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router:Router) {

   }
  login()
  {
    console.log(this.model);
    this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(value=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      this.logInWorked=true;
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.logInWorked!=true && this.authService.loggedIn()){
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
  }

  }
```

Comment: You can try to avoid writing new `LoggedGuard ` by using `!` operator. But give a try. `canActivate: [ !AuthGuard],`

Answer (score 2):

You can create new LoggedGuardService where you are checking whether user is logged in:

```
export class LoggedGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router:Router){

    }
    canActivate(): boolean{
       if (!this.authService.loggedIn()){
         return true;
       }
       else{
         this.router.navigate(['']);
       }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedGuard]
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

As i can see you have written `AuthGuard` then you just have to check in `AuthGuard` if the user has already logged in or not. If user is logged in return `false` otherwise return `true`.

Comment: I edited and added my authGuard class.Its responsible for protecting whether user logged in or not already.

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek  when this condition : `if(this.authService.loggedIn())` is true you should return false.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an Angular template that deals with most navigation cases. Look at AuthGuard in my project to have an example on how to implement this: https://github.com/francescodist/matFortyTwo/blob/master/src/app/auth/auth.guard.ts